# Optimize server side Experiments gtag

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, google-optimize

The docs for Google optimize server side events are written for analytics.js is there a way to do the same thing using gtag.js? https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments#add-ga-tracking-code-to-variations

```
ga('set', 'exp', `${experimentId}.${variationId}`);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I'm using gtag so I need something like this:

```
gtag('event', '???', {
???: `${experimentId}.${variantPosition}`,
});
```

I tried these:

```
window.gtag('set', { expId: <experiment-id> });
window.gtag('set', { expVar: <variation-number> });
window.gtag('event', 'page_view', ...
```

and

```
window.gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', {experiments: [ { id: 'ExperimentID 1', variant: '1' }, { id: 'ExperimentID 2', variant: '2' }, ]});
```

Neither of these works, in optimize `Details` tab I cannot see any active sessions. Anyone solved this issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I managed to find a solution, for anyone wondering how to do it, this is it:

```
window.gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX', {
  experiments: [{ id: experimentId, variant: experimentVariation }],
});
```

where `experimentId` is id supplied by Optimize and `variant` is a digit representing active user experiment, for example `1` or `2`.

Comment: I believe this code snippet is outdated: https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments?technology=ga4#add-ga-tracking-code-to-variants